# Data embedding in a binary image using python

Tags: python, steganography

I'm new to python and I'm attempting to improve on an existing method of embedding data in a binary image with minimal visual distortion. The current method that I am trying to implement needs to have a 3x3 moving window that centers on each pixel and analyses the smoothness of the area within the window and the amount of black and white clusters. This information would then be passed into a decision module that will decide on the best pixel to alter in order to embed data. I've played around with PIL and numPy, but without much success so any suggestions to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can check [Hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/) project. It's a set of python library / tools to dissect files, even if you don't know the format.
In your case, you might be interested about one of their example in hachoir-tools :

https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/src/2a6cad1599c6/hachoir-tools/steganography.py

They demonstrate how you can add hidden data in mpeg audio and png format. Feel free to support your own format :)